# Access nested body property from HTTP resolver(AppSync)

Tags: aws-appsync, vtl, aws-appsync-resolver

I'm new to AWS AppSync and I am trying to access certain body property(from HTTP response) in my resolver's response mapping template.
For example: I am able to present the response as is via `$util.toJson($ctx.result.body)`, but when I try to get some of the nested body properties it fails.

For example, imagine the body looks like this:

```
{
  about:{
    "firstName":"Chuck",
    "lastName":"Norris"
  }
}
```

and `$util.toJson($ctx.result.body.about)` returns `null`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way extract the parsed body in the following way:

```
#set ($parsed_body = $util.parseJson($ctx.result.body))
```

And then I am able to access the properties via dot notation:

```
parsed_body.about.firstName
```

The part I was missing is `$util.parseJson(<json-string>)`

It seems that the body is a JSON string.